# How to read .txt file from email using apps script

Tags: email, google-apps-script

I'm currently trying to make a program that pulls emails from a specified sender reads the .txt file attached to that email (contains my work schedule as a text file) and imports it into my calendar. I have almost everything working but always get these diamond-shaped characters each time I try to extract the text from the .txt file. This is the current code I'm using to extract it.

```java
function testMain()
{
  var emails = getEmailsBySender(sendersEmail);
  Logger.log(emails[0].getAttachments()[0].getAllBlobs()[0].getDataAsString());
}
```

`getEmailsBySender(sendersEmail)` is the function I wrote that returns the specific email with the text attachment. The response I keep getting looks like this `��1`. I also did some research and some people were suggesting adding an offset to `getDataAsString()` like this `getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1')`, but that just returned this `ÿþ1`. Do I need to modify the offset again or am I missing something else?

Comment: In order to reproduce this, can you provide the content of the `.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GmailAttachment is already a blob. Please check the documentation.

```js
emails[0].getAttachments()[0].getDataAsString()
```

Reference:
[GmailAttachment.getDataAsString](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-attachment?hl=en#getDataAsString())

Comment: I tried that already, still gives me this `��1`

Comment: pass the charset `getDataAsString(charset)` and you will get the content

Comment: Did that too and that just returns `ÿþ1`, I don't know if its the right charset but I'm using `ISO-8859-1`. The file is just a plain .txt file, what am I missing?

Comment: `charset` may be any value, it is set by the editor when saving the file, why may differ among his OS language and/or application. It is to some mean trial and error. Have you tried `US_ASCII`? Manually you may be able to detect by opening with Microsoft Word.

Comment: Just tried `US_ASCII`, it returned an invalid argument error. How could I detect this manually with Word? Where would I look, and also where could I find a list of offsets to try or how would I go about this game of guess and check? Sorry for all the questions, this is now totally new stuff to me.

Comment: Open the txt with chrome. Type and run `document.characterSet` in the console (Press F12 to open it).

Comment: Thank you so much! It ended up being `UTF-16LE`, I don't think I ever would have figured that one out on my own XD